# Running sstableloader from several nodes

Tags: cassandra

With the objective of speeding up the migration process of a full production cassandra cluster, I would like to know if anyone has tried to simultaneously run cassandra's sstableloader from two nodes at the same time.

Those nodes would be out of the destination cassandra's ring and they would stream different data to the ring.

Has anyone tried this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this with multiple simultaneous sstableloaders without any issue. In my case the SSTable-sets were created by a map-reduce job resulting in a set of SSTables per reducer that were later loaded via the sstableloader.